# Force to open back camera on iPhone

Tags: php, html

I have this in my html5

```
<input name="photoAutomatic" id="automatic" type="file" capture="user" accept="image/jpeg" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 d-none"/>
```

but every time I click this input, it uses the front selfie camera. How can I set it so that it uses the back cam instead?

I'm using html5 + php

Comment: @Harith That is not a duplicate.  The `getUserMedia()` API is unrelated to the file input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `capture="user"` to `capture="environment"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture

Alternatively, simply don't set the `capture` attribute's value.  It's often best to just leave these things up to the system default.  Usually, the back-facing/environment camera would be used by default.